# Angular ngIf to add selected attribute to option where value is string

Tags: html, angular, angular-ng-if

I want to dynamically add the `selected` attribute to `option` of `select` drop-down list.

So something like this

```
 <select name="gcodeProfile">
        <option value="HT Translucent F WF 500 um.gcode.profile" *ngIf='[attr.value] === {{resinFileToLoad.gcodeProfile}}; [attr.selected] = true'>HT Translucent F WF 500 um.gcode.profile</option>
        <option value="HT Translucent F WF 500 um.gcode.profile-niki-safe" *ngIf='[attr.value] === {{resinFileToLoad.gcodeProfile}}; [attr.selected] = true'>HT Translucent F WF 500 um.gcode.profile-niki-safe</option>
 </select>
```

Where

```
resinFileToLoad.gcodeProfile = 'HT Translucent F WF 500 um.gcode.profile';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition should actually bound be to the `[selected]` property. The `attr` isn't required for `selected` attribute and neither is the `*ngIf` directive.

Try the following

```html
<select name="gcodeProfile">
  <option 
    value="HT Translucent F WF 500 um.gcode.profile" 
    [selected]="resinFileToLoad.gcodeProfile === 'HT Translucent F WF 500 um.gcode.profile'"
  >
    HT Translucent F WF 500 um.gcode.profile
  </option>
  <option 
    value="HT Translucent F WF 500 um.gcode.profile-niki-safe" 
    [selected]="resinFileToLoad.gcodeProfile === 'HT Translucent F WF 500 um.gcode.profile-niki-safe'"
  >
    HT Translucent F WF 500 um.gcode.profile-niki-safe
  </option>
</select>
```

The single quotes inside the double-quotes denotes string literal in the comparison expression.

#### Update: Use the value from `value` attribute

You could assign template reference variables to options and access it's value in the comparison. Try the following

```html
<select name="gcodeProfile">
  <option #option1
    value="HT Translucent F WF 500 um.gcode.profile" 
    [selected]="resinFileToLoad.gcodeProfile === option1.value"
  >
    HT Translucent F WF 500 um.gcode.profile
  </option>
  <option #option2
    value="HT Translucent F WF 500 um.gcode.profile-niki-safe" 
    [selected]="resinFileToLoad.gcodeProfile === option2.value"
  >
    HT Translucent F WF 500 um.gcode.profile-niki-safe
  </option>
</select>
```

Here `option1` and `option2` are the template reference variables for option 1 and 2 respectively. Also note the lack of single quotes since we aren't using string literals anymore.

#### Update: bind using `[(ngModel)]`

The above solutions are only quick fixes for short dropdowns. If you need a scalable solution, you either need to use template driven forms or reactive forms.

The template driven forms would be the quickest to get started with. Instead of using `value` and `selected` attributes, you can two-way bind the default value to `ngModel` property.

Try the following

```html
<select name="gcodeProfile" [(ngModel)]="resinFileToLoad.ZDir">
  <option> 1 </option>
  <option> 2 </option>
  <option> 3 </option>
  ...
</select>
```

Now the default value is bound to the `resinFileToLoad.ZDir` variable. So if you do something like `{{ resinFileToLoad.ZDir }}` in the template, you can see that the value changes accd. to the drop-down selection. If you do not wish to have this behavior i.e., to retain the value of `resinFileToLoad.ZDir`, you could remove the event binding and use only `[ngModel]="resinFileToLoad.ZDir"`.

Comment: This has worked almost perfectly for my need, I am going to accept your answer but maybe you know how I can instead of writing out the value text use something like thisOption.value?

Comment: Yes you could use template reference variables. I've updated the answer.

Comment: These solutions are only quick fixes for short drop-downs. For a better solution, you could use template driven forms or reactive forms. I've updated the answer. And you don't have to apologize, people here know what they signed up for :).